# Interchangeable GUI toolkit for textmode and graphical mode

Tags: windows, user-interface, cross-platform, ncurses

I am looking for a cross platform GUI toolkit (for C) that works equally well in the terminal as it does in the "graphical world".

What (I think) I want is something like ncurses but with the option to set the guimode before starting. So for example if my program is started from the commandline I can go textmode and if it is started from X or Windows or whatever I can instead start a graphical GUI using the same API. Something like this...

guimode=TEXTMODEGUI;
or
guimode=GRAPHICALGUI;
before doing something like this...

drawwindow("title","text");

I have not found any ncurses to gtk+/wx/qt/whatever wrappers so far. Does something like this exits?!

Comment: This could be quite a challenge, given that the semantics of ncurses are not easily mappable to those of GTK+ and friends.

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to accept C++ for the GUI part, use libyui from the YaST project. It supports Qt, Gtk and ncurses. I answered a similar question to yours [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2730371/203718).

Comment: Thanks Duncan, Sadly I am not willing to go C++ ;) but I'll check it out anyways!

Answer (score 1):

The only project I've run into like this is [Charva](http://www.pitman.co.za/projects/charva/index.html) for Java.  I have not used it and there appears to be no development since 2006.